# How to add Users in a Remarketing UserList using Google Ads API?

Tags: java, google-ads-api, google-remarketing-audience

I'm trying to create a remarketing userList add some users into it using the Java implementation for Google Ads Api.

The custom audience creation part looks fine, I can see it created in the Ads plataform, but looks like the users wasn't included into it.

[Print screen: Empty custom audience inside google ads plataform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ceCG.png)

I'm sending a JsonArray with 2000 user as parameter and hashing it inside this function, and used [this samples](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/samples/java/remarketing) as reference.

I'm not sure if I misunderstood [the documentation](https://developers.google.cn/adwords/api/docs/guides/remarketing?hl=zh-cn) or if I'm including the userList in a wrong way or anything like that.

```
    public JsonArray uploadJsonList(String customerId, JsonArray jsonUsers) throws Exception {
      
        List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
        JsonObject hashedObj = new JsonObject();
        JsonArray arrayJsonHashed = new JsonArray();
                
        for (JsonValue jsonValue : jsonUsers) {
            
            JsonObject obj = jsonValue.asObject();
            hashedObj = new JsonObject();
            
            //Getting user data
            String normalizedEmail = textUtils.toNormalizedString(obj.get("PESSOA_EMAIL1").toString());
            String normalizedPhone = textUtils.toNormalizedString(obj.get("PESSOA_CELULAR").toString()); 
            String normalizedId = obj.get("PESSOA_ID").toString(); 
            normalizedId = removeFirstandLast(normalizedId);
        
            //Hashing user data
            hashedObj.add("pessoa_email1", textUtils.toSHA256String(normalizedEmail));
            hashedObj.add("pessoa_celular", textUtils.toSHA256String(normalizedPhone));
            hashedObj.add("pessoa_id",normalizedId);
            arrayJsonHashed.add(hashedObj);
            
            //Creating a member list
            Member member = new Member();
            member.setHashedEmail(textUtils.toSHA256String(normalizedEmail));
            member.setHashedPhoneNumber(textUtils.toSHA256String(normalizedPhone));
            members.add(member);         
        }
        
        //starting ads services
        AdWordsServices adWordsServices = new AdWordsServices();
        Customer[] customers = getCustomers(adWordsServices, session);
        session.setClientCustomerId(customerId);
        AdwordsUserListServiceInterface userListService = adWordsServices.get(session, AdwordsUserListServiceInterface.class);
        
        // Create a user list.
        CrmBasedUserList userList = new CrmBasedUserList();
        userList.setName("Test Remarketing Custom Audience - " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        userList.setDescription("A list of customers that was readed from big query");
        
        // CRM-based user lists can use a membershipLifeSpan of 10000 to indicate unlimited; otherwise
        // normal values apply.
        userList.setMembershipLifeSpan(100L);
        userList.setUploadKeyType(CustomerMatchUploadKeyType.CONTACT_INFO);                
        
        // Create operation.
        UserListOperation operation = new UserListOperation();
        operation.setOperand(userList);
        operation.setOperator(Operator.ADD);

        // Add user list.
        UserListReturnValue result = userListService.mutate(new UserListOperation[]{operation});

        // Display user list.
        UserList userListAdded = result.getValue(0);
        System.out.printf(
                "User list with name '%s' and ID %d was added.%n",
                userListAdded.getName(), userListAdded.getId());

        // Get user list ID.
        Long userListId = userListAdded.getId();

        // Create operation to add members to the user list based on email addresses.
        MutateMembersOperation mutateMembersOperation = new MutateMembersOperation();
        MutateMembersOperand operand = new MutateMembersOperand();

        operand.setUserListId(userListId);
        operand.setMembersList(members.toArray(new Member[members.size()]));   
        
        mutateMembersOperation.setOperand(operand);
        mutateMembersOperation.setOperator(Operator.ADD);
        
        // Add members to the user list based on email addresses.
        MutateMembersReturnValue mutateMembersResult =
                userListService.mutateMembers(new MutateMembersOperation[]{mutateMembersOperation});

        // Display results.
        // Reminder: it may take several hours for the list to be populated with members.
        for (UserList userListResult : mutateMembersResult.getUserLists()) {
            System.out.printf(
                    "%d email addresses were uploaded to user list with name '%s' and ID %d "
                            + "and are scheduled for review.%n",
                            members.size(), userListResult.getName(), userListResult.getId());
        }
                
        return arrayJsonHashed;
    }
```

Comment: You still needing help with this?